# Internal social chat mobile - PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, mobile, chat, organization

We're going to build mobile application that will have internal social chat for the organization.
This chat can be done between individuals or groups.
I would like to know if there is already relevant frameworks that I can use.

Our application will be built based on PhoneGap, so it'll be good if this framework can be part of the solution.

Thank you,
Moshe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Parse for this purpose. Check out the links

http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com

https://parse.com/

Hopefully it helps. I have used to build something similar (on a small scale) using Parse. Good Luck

Comment: Alik - thank you. It's support multi-platform? iOS and Android?

Comment: @Moshe Yes it supports both iOS and Android and others too i.e web etc. Do give it a try. Upvote or accept the answer as correct if it was helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). This may be what you want.

Comment: Hi ElFik, thank you. I need a solution for on-premise intranet based users and I need solution that will be good for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Ah, sorry Moshe, I misunderstood. Unfortunately I have no experience with PhoneGap or any similar framework, so I can't help here.